# Is it possible to connect a Domain Controller (Windows Server 2012) with SBS 2011?

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-server-2012, windows-sbs-2011

We're trying to connect a Windows Server 2012 with a SBS 2011 server. The plan is to make Windows Server 2012 run as a Domain Controller and have the SBS 2011 server function as an Exchange Server.

We're not even sure if this is possible.. but if it is, does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SBS 2011 Premium, then you can have additional servers on the same network. If you have Essentials, you cannot have any other Windows servers on the same network.

That said, you should really just use a non-SBS version of Windows Server if you're needing multiple within the environment.

Comment: Thanks. Our plan was to add SBS2011 to the Server 2012 (essentials) Domain Controller as the server that'll handle Exchange.But you're saying we should drop all that and go for a non-sbs/essentials version of both servers? So for example, Server 2012 standard and Server 2008 running Exchange?

Comment: I would do that instead, yes.